# Replace classname after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I am trying to replace classname after ajax has been loaded (updated to table) , when i did a console log on my code for

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
          console.log(x)
 });
```

it will print this, i am able to access the tag by clicking on it and see that the specific dom is being selected on my web. Everytime after ajax is called, it will refresh the table but not the page.

```
HTMLCollection(12) [tbody, tbody, tbody.linked-visual-table, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody]
length: 12
0: tbody
1: tbody
2: tbody.linked-visual-table
3: tbody
rows: HTMLCollection(27) [tr.viz-tr-header, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr, tr]
align: ""
ch: ""
chOff: ""
vAlign: ""
title: ""
lang: ""
translate: true
```

i tried this to log xhr and this is what it returns

```
{url: "/arc/sqlrun/jsonselect_parallel", type: "POST", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true, …}
url: "/arc/sqlrun/jsonselect_parallel"
type: "POST"
isLocal: false
global: true
processData: true
async: true
```

when i tried to select a specific index on my html collection and i did `console.log(x[3])`

it will print , but i when i click on the tag was print out on my console log, it is not highlighting anything on my browser, i believed that all dom was being replace . what i am trying to achieve is

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
          console.log(x)
        //Find td that has string of 'go' and add class green
        //Find td that has string of 'Stop' and add class red 
 });
```

Ive been trying to tackle this problem for days but i feel i am missing some step. everytime when new data is loaded on table, it will remove classname that was assigned

i have tried queryselector and indexing of array, all have returned Node cannot be found in the current page.

**update**

i have implemented @manikant gautam   solution, it appends to almost all but skip to the one i needed the class to be appended.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
        //var x = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");
         console.log(x)
         addClasses();
      });

    function addClasses(){
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
         for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
              x[i].className += " custom";
         }
```

in my console log, it seems it is avoiding any custom class to be appended to that specific tag , but why?

```
HTMLCollection(12) [tbody, tbody, tbody.linked-visual-table, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody]
length: 12
0: tbody..custom
1: tbody..custom
2: tbody.linked-visual-table.custom
3: tbody
4: tbody..custom
5: tbody..custom
6: tbody..custom
7: tbody..custom
8: tbody..custom
9: tbody..custom
10: tbody..custom
11: tbody..custom
__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

only at index 3 has values, all the the indexes on tbody other than 3 which has classname assign has no values at all. does this mean, it automatically create a new div after it is refresh on ajax?

```
HTMLCollection(12) [tbody, tbody, tbody.linked-visual-table, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody, tbody]
length: 12
0: tbody..custom
1: tbody..custom
2: tbody.linked-visual-table.custom
3: tbody
rows: HTMLCollection(19)
length: 19
0: tr.viz-tr-header
1: tr
2: tr
3: tr
```

Answer (score 1):

`.addClass('Green')` you have to applied after matching condition.

```
  $( document ).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
      console.log(x)
    //Find td that has string of 'go' and add class green
    //Find td that has string of 'Stop' and add class red 
    addClasses();
   });
    function addClasses(){
        var t = document.getElementById("table");
        var trs = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var tds = null;

       for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++){
            tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
                  for (var n=0; n<tds.length;n++) {
               if(tds[n].innerHTML.contains("Go")){
                 $(tds[n]).addClass('Green');
               }
               if(tds[n].innerHTML.contains("Stop")){
                 $(tds[n]).addClass('Red');
               }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @manikant gautam, i tried your solution . Only problem is that once i have assigned the class name , it skip to the one that i need the custom class. i have updated my question for easier view. Thanks

Comment: @user12883347 check the text it might not have text including `Go or Stop`

Comment: Yes youre right, there are no rows in tbody that ive assigned the classname. the one that has the rows only apply to the one that does not have the classname which it seems impossible for me to assign a classname for it

Comment: @user12883347 `addClass` simply add `Class` if there isn't any class on elements it will add one. Check the `HTML text` because condition on `text` inside `td`. A/c to condn. it will only add classes to those `td's` whose `HTML` contains either `Go` or `Stop`

Comment: when i did a for loop to check all elements, when i check all element individually , it states that all element has the classname assign.i am not sure how can i retrieve what was printed out after the refresh of table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
  var x = document.querySelector("tbody");
  let td = x.querySelectorAll('td');
  td.forEach( item => {
    if(item.textContent.includes('go')){ // or can be more specific with `===`
      item.classList.add('green');
    } else if(item.textContent.includes('Stop')) {
      item.classList.add('red');
    }
  });
});
```

**Example**

```js
(function() {
    var x = document.querySelector("tbody");
    let td = x.querySelectorAll("td");
    td.forEach(item => {
      if (item.textContent === "go") {
        item.classList.add("green");
      } else if (item.textContent === "Stop") {
        item.classList.add("red");
      }
    });
})();
```

```css
.green {
        background-color: green;
      }

      .red {
        background-color: red;
      }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>go</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Stop</td>
        <td>go</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>go</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Stop</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: i have tried our solution but its returning `Node cannot be found in the current page.`

Comment: Then it's mean not td exist in the page.

Comment: I have updated the question,when i did a console log. it appeared my log .

Comment: I am not sure on that, i am adding a custom css on top of an analytical web.